# Representing a graph as backbone.js model/collection

Tags: backbone.js, graph

I am looking for an example how to represent a Graph and its Nodes and Edges as a backbone.js model. I hope somebody can point me to an example how to do this elegantly.

Thanks

martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Assuming you'd like to store metadata with the nodes - like name etc)

A simple way might be representing the graph as a collection of node models.

Each of these models would have a property containing an array of edges represented by the id of the node they connect to - so that `collection.toJSON()` would return something like:

```
[
   {
     id: 1,
     name: 'first node',
     edges: [2, 4]
   },
   {
     id: 2,
     name: 'second node',
     edges: [1, 3, 4]
   },
   {
     id: 3,
     name: 'third node',
     edges: [2]
   },
   {
     id: 1,
     name: 'first node',
     edges: [1, 2]
   }
]
```

The you could implement methods to calculate the distance between nodes or derive clusters in the collection class.

Now as I mentioned this is a *simple* implementation, which might be woefully inefficient depending on the operations you would like to do on the graph.

If you'd like to do some reading and find the most efficient way to store graph information in a hash-like (model) or list-like (collection) structure, google "Adjacency matrix" or "Adjacency list" and go from there!

Comment: thanks a lot for you reply - i am kind of going that way right now, not yet sure how it will turn out yet ...